# Why result from WMI is different in standard mode and administrator user in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, delphi, winapi

I want to protect my application. So I read hard drive serial number and compare. The application has good result in administrator user mode but it has bad result in standard user mode.

I wrote my application with C#. But for reading hard drive serial number I used a dll file that I wrote in Delphi.

```pascal
hDevice := CreateFile( '\\.\PhysicalDrive0:', GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE , nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0 );
```

I try using NET so I used WMI class `Win32_DiskDrive` but this method has bad results in standard user mode too.

```cs
private string getserial()
{
    string SerialNumber = "";
    string dataForSerial = string.Empty;
    ManagementObjectSearcher Finder = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem");
    string Name = "";

    foreach (ManagementObject OS in Finder.Get()) Name = OS["Name"].ToString();

    // Name = "Microsoft Windows XP Professional|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1" 

    int ind = Name.IndexOf("Harddisk") + 8;
    int HardIndex = Convert.ToInt16(Name.Substring(ind, 1));
    Finder = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE Index=" + HardIndex);
    foreach (ManagementObject HardDisks in Finder.Get())
        foreach (ManagementObject HardDisk in HardDisks.GetRelated("Win32_PhysicalMedia"))
            SerialNumber = HardDisk["SerialNumber"].ToString();

    // SerialNumber = dataForSerial;

    return SerialNumber;
}
```

In standard user mode:

1. In case of the Delphi dll it throws an access denied error
2. In case of the WMI the output is different in standard user vs administrator user.

**Note**: this problem (NO.2) is only in Windows 7.

Comment: In case 2, what are the two outputs?

Comment: Please respond to presented requests for additional information. What other OS's have you tried in addition to Windows 7?

Comment: It is a pity that you seem to ignore people who have an interest in helping you. From your public data I see that you have visited the site after my previous comment, and thus you have been notified about my comment. Yet, no response. Good luck.

Comment: output in mode standard user is a string of hex and output in mode administrator user is a string of Ascii.when i converted hex to Ascii so compare them aren't equle.

Comment: In windows 10 output in mose standard and administrator are equle.

Comment: @mohamadzandi again, what are the ACTUAL outputs you are seeing in both modes? Please show the full Delphi code, you have shown only the full WMI code.

Comment: @mohamadzandi FWIW, using a HDD serial number to "protect" your software is not a very good deterrent, non-casual hackers who really want to break your protection will likely be asked to do so pretty easily, especially when the code to get the serial is in a DLL that can be replaced with another DLL to return faulty serials. Where and how does your software validate the serial is real? Are you at least signing the DLL and validating its signature to avoid tampering? There are actual commercial products designed to protect software, you should look into them

Comment: output in mode administrator user is "    WD-WMAMD8274948" and output in mode standard user is "2020202057202d444d574d413844373239343834"

Comment: I want to use wmi ,because delphi dll can't run command createfile in mode standar user

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following code when calling `CreateFile` to access the physical disk. It works without admin rights and allows one to read the drive's properties:

```
hDisk := CreateFile ('\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0', 0, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NIL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                     FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL or FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, 0);
```

Please also take note that the name of the drive passed as the first parameter to CreateFile does not include a colon ":" at the end.

Comment: You'r code  return   variable "hdisk"  in mode administrator user and standard user incorrect. only difference is that not giving message access denied

Comment: Using the `CreateFile` call as described above and subsequent calls to `DeviceIoControl` I am perfectly able without admin rights to query a disk's properties. I do not have a clue why this does not work for you, but as you are not showing any of the code you use in your DLL (see [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example] (How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example) I do not see how I can help you any further.

Comment: I showed complete code(get serial number hard drive by WMI).The important question is why result is different in mode administrator user and standard user in windows 7.
output in mode administrator user is " WD-WMAMD8274948" and output in mode standard user is "2020202057202d444d574d413844373239343834"

Answer (score 1):

Please see this [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8523d7b9-0dc8-4d87-be69-a482aec9ee5e/wmi-win32physicalmedia-smart-id-in-vista-and-7-permissions?forum=netfxbcl). Results are varying depending on Windows version, on whether the code is run as admin or not, and whether the `Win32_PhysicalMedia` class is used or the `Win32_DiskDrive` class. Seems pretty unreliable, you may have to write your own abstraction layer to handle it yourself, as described in these forum posts.

I tried it myself and found I got two different serial numbers depending on admin vs normal and `Win32_PhysicalMedia` vs `Win32_DiskDrive`:

`VB38bb50ab-0de50c12`

and

`42563833626230356261302d6564303531632032`

Notice that the second string is actually a `hex-encoded` and `byte-reversed` version of the first string!